# NameError: uninitialized constant, with RSpec

Tags: rspec, rake, jruby, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to test my Jenkins Ruby plugin with RSpec.
My emailcomputerlistener.rb:

```
require 'net/smtp'
class EmailComputerListener
  include Jenkins::Slaves::ComputerListener
  def online(computer, listener)
    [...]
  end
end
```

My emailcomputerlistener_spec.rb

```
require 'emailcomputerlistener'
require 'computer' # overloaded class for computer
require 'smtp'     # overloaded smtp class
require 'computerlistener' # required?

describe EmailComputerListener do
  before :each do
    @ecl = EmailComputerListener.new
    [...]
  end
[tests]
end
```

When running RSpec, it says:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant EmailComputerListener::Jenkins
[row 3]
```

All files are in the same directory, I have been running my tests on a separate emailcomputerlistener with the include statement commented out to make the tests pass. But it would be better to test the original file obviously.

Edit: The test do not rely on Jenkins::Slaves::ComputerListener, nor should they, ComputerListener is defined in a gem I'm bundling my plugin with. All I'm trying to do is simulating this file, I cannot add a `require 'computerlistener'` in EmailComputerListener since doing so would probably break the plugin.

Thanks.

Comment: Det där lägger du av med, direkt!

Comment: Kan stolt meddela att du blivit tilldelad en down vote av mig :)

Answer (score 0):

since you removed the stacktrace i need to guess that the error is coming from line 3 in your `EmailComputerListener`:

```
include Jenkins::Slaves::ComputerListener
```

i also conclude that this is defined in your `computerlistener.rb` file which you require in your spec.

there are several bad things about this setup:

- you should match your classes with your files:

`EmailComputerListener` => `email_computer_listener.rb`

- you should match your directory structure with your modules:

`Jenkins::Slaves::ComputerListener` => `jenkins/slaves/computer_listener.rb`

- you should require the files where they are used or at the root

so `require 'jenkins/slaves/computer_listener'` should go at the top of your scripts root file. in your case to `email_computer_listener.rb`.